# How can I test these RSS parsing service objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, service, rspec

I have some service objects that use Nokogiri to make AR instances. I created a rake task so that I can update the instances with a cron job. What I want to test is if it's adding items that weren't there before, ie:

- Create an `Importer` with a `url` of `spec/fixtures/feed.xml`, feed.xml having 10 items.
- Expect `Show.count == 1` and `Episode.count == 10`
- Edit `spec/fixtures/feed.xml` to have 11 items
- Invoke rake task
- Expect `Show.count == 1` and `Episode.count == 11`

How could I test this in RSpec, or modify my code to be more testable?

```
# models/importer.rb
class Importer < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :parse_importer

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true
  validates :feed_format, presence: true

  private

  def parse_importer
    Parser.new(self)
  end
end

# models/show.rb
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true

  has_many :episodes

  attr_accessor :entries
end

# models/episode.rb
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :title, uniqueness: true

  belongs_to :show
end

#lib/tasks/admin.rake
namespace :admin do
  desc "Checks all Importer URLs for new items."
  task refresh: :environment do
    @importers = Importer.all

    @importers.each do |importer|
      Parser.new(importer)
    end
  end
end

# services/parser.rb
class Parser
  def initialize(importer)
    feed = Feed.new(importer)
    show = Show.where(rss_link: importer.url).first

    if show # add new episodes
      new_episodes = Itunes::Channel.refresh(feed.origin)

      new_episodes.each do |new_episode|
        show.episodes.create feed.episode(new_episode)
      end
    else # create a show and its episodes
      new_show = Show.new(feed.show) if (feed && feed.show)

      if (new_show.save && new_show.entries.any?)
        new_show.entries.each do |entry|
          new_show.episodes.create feed.episode(entry)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# services/feed.rb
class Feed
  require "nokogiri"
  require "open-uri"
  require "formats/itunes"

  attr_reader :params, :origin, :show, :episode

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def origin
    @origin = Nokogiri::XML(open(params[:url]))
  end

  def format
    @format = params[:feed_format]
  end

  def show
    case format
      when "iTunes"
        Itunes::Channel.fresh(origin)
    end
  end

  def episode(entry)
    @entry = entry

    case format
      when "iTunes"
        Itunes::Item.fresh(@entry)
    end
  end
end

# services/formats/itunes.rb
class Itunes
  class Channel
    def initialize(origin)
      @origin = origin
    end

    def title
      @origin.xpath("//channel/title").text
    end

    def description
      @origin.xpath("//channel/description").text
    end

    def summary
      @origin.xpath("//channel/*[name()='itunes:summary']").text
    end

    def subtitle
      @origin.xpath("//channel/*[name()='itunes:subtitle']/text()").text
    end

    def rss_link
      @origin.xpath("//channel/*[name()='atom:link']/@href").text
    end

    def main_link
      @origin.xpath("//channel/link/text()").text
    end

    def docs_link
      @origin.xpath("//channel/docs/text()").text
    end

    def release
      @origin.xpath("//channel/pubDate/text()").text
    end

    def image
      @origin.xpath("//channel/image/url/text()").text
    end

    def language
      @origin.xpath("//channel/language/text()").text
    end

    def keywords
      keywords_array(@origin)
    end

    def categories
      category_array(@origin)
    end

    def explicit
      explicit_check(@origin)
    end

    def entries
      entry_array(@origin)
    end

    def self.fresh(origin)
      @show = Itunes::Channel.new origin

      return {
        description: @show.description,
        release: @show.release,
        explicit: @show.explicit,
        language: @show.language,
        title: @show.title,
        summary: @show.summary,
        subtitle: @show.subtitle,
        image: @show.image,
        rss_link: @show.rss_link,
        main_link: @show.main_link,
        docs_link: @show.docs_link,
        categories: @show.categories,
        keywords: @show.keywords,
        entries: @show.entries
      }
    end

    def self.refresh(origin)
      @show = Itunes::Channel.new origin
      return @show.entries
    end

    private

    def category_array(channel)
      arr = []
      channel.xpath("//channel/*[name()='itunes:category']/@text").each do |category|
        arr.push(category.to_s)
      end
      return arr
    end

    def explicit_check(channel)
      string = channel.xpath("//channel/*[name()='itunes:explicit']").text

      if string === "yes" || string === "Yes"
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end

    def keywords_array(channel)
      keywords = channel.xpath("//channel/*[name()='itunes:keywords']/text()").text
      arr = keywords.split(",")
      return arr
    end

    def entry_array(channel)
      arr = []
      channel.xpath("//item").each do |item|
        arr.push(item)
      end
      return arr
    end
  end

  class Item
    def initialize(origin)
      @origin = origin
    end

    def description
      @origin.xpath("*[name()='itunes:subtitle']").text
    end

    def release
      @origin.xpath("pubDate").text
    end

    def image
      @origin.xpath("*[name()='itunes:image']/@href").text
    end

    def explicit
      explicit_check(@origin)
    end

    def duration
      @origin.xpath("*[name()='itunes:duration']").text
    end

    def title
      @origin.xpath("title").text
    end

    def enclosure_url
      @origin.xpath("enclosure/@url").text
    end

    def enclosure_length
      @origin.xpath("enclosure/@length").text
    end

    def enclosure_type
      @origin.xpath("enclosure/@type").text
    end

    def keywords
      keywords_array(@origin.xpath("*[name()='itunes:keywords']").text)
    end

    def self.fresh(entry)
      @episode = Itunes::Item.new entry

      return {
        description: @episode.description,
        release: @episode.release,
        image: @episode.image,
        explicit: @episode.explicit,
        duration: @episode.duration,
        title: @episode.title,
        enclosure_url: @episode.enclosure_url,
        enclosure_length: @episode.enclosure_length,
        enclosure_type: @episode.enclosure_type,
        keywords: @episode.keywords
      }
    end

    private

    def explicit_check(item)
      string = item.xpath("*[name()='itunes:explicit']").text

      if string === "yes" || string === "Yes"
        true
      else
        false
      end
    end

    def keywords_array(item)
      keywords = item.split(",")
      return keywords
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before anything else, good for you for using service objects! I've been using this approach a great deal and find POROs preferable to fat models in many situations.

It appears the behavior you're interested in testing is contained in `Parser.initialize`.

First, I'd create a class method for `Parser` called `parse`. IMO, `Parser.parse(importer)` is clearer about what `Parser` is doing than is `Parser.new(importer)`. So, it might look like:

```
#services/parser.rb
class Parser
  class << self

    def parse(importer)
      @importer = importer
      @feed = Feed.new(importer)

      if @show = Show.where(rss_link: importer.url).first
        create_new_episodes Itunes::Channel.refresh(@feed.origin)
      else
        create_show_and_episodes
      end
    end # parse

  end
end
```

Then add the `create_new_episodes` and `create_show_and_episodes` class methods.

```
#services/parser.rb
class Parser
  class << self

    def parse(importer)
      @importer = importer
      @feed     = Feed.new(importer)

      if @show = Show.where(rss_link: @importer.url).first
        create_new_episodes Itunes::Channel.refresh(@feed.origin)
      else
        create_show_and_episodes
      end
    end # parse

    def create_new_episodes(new_episodes)
      new_episodes.each do |new_episode|
        @show.episodes.create @feed.episode(new_episode)
      end
    end # create_new_episodes

    def create_show_and_episodes
      new_show = Show.new(@feed.show) if (@feed && @feed.show)

      if (new_show.save && new_show.entries.any?)
        new_show.entries.each do |entry|
          new_show.episodes.create @feed.episode(entry)
        end
      end
    end # create_show_and_episodes

  end
end
```

Now you have a `Parser.create_new_episodes` method that you can test independently. So, your test might look something like:

```
require 'rspec_helper'

describe Parser do
  describe '.create_new_episodes' do
    context 'when an initial parse has been completed' do 
      before(:each) do
        first_file = Nokogiri::XML(open('spec/fixtures/feed_1.xml'))
        @second_file = Nokogiri::XML(open('spec/fixtures/feed_2.xml'))
        Parser.create_show_and_episodes first_file
      end
      it 'changes Episodes.count by 1' do
        expect{Parser.create_new_episodes(@second_file)}.to change{Episodes.count}.by(1)
      end
      it 'changes Show.count by 0' do
        expect{Parser.create_new_episodes(@second_file)}.to change{Show.count}.by(0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Naturally, you'll need `feed_1.xml` and `feed_2.xml` in the `spec\fixtures` directory.

Apologies for any typos. And, I didn't run the code. So, might be buggy. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks. Someone here recommended them and I like them quite a bit. I got rid of `Feed` and refactored `Parser` so that `create_show_and_episodes` and `create_new_episodes` accept URLs. Everything works in development, but the tests are failing. I set the atom link in both to `spec/fixtures/feed_1.xml` so that `@show = Show.where(rss_link: url).first` would think they're the same. I'll edit my post to reflect the changes I made - let me know what you think.